# Loading the Iris Dataset in from a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scikit-learn

I am practicing data processing with Scikit learn, and I'm looking at Classification Probability. I've successfully ran the model using the data set from `import dataset` now I want to try and do the same thing with a CSV file, so I've downloaded the same dataset, and am trying to load it into my code.

```
iris = np.loadtxt('./iris.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
X = iris.data[:, 0:2]
y = iris.target
```

However I get an error stating `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'setosa'` I understand that this is from the CSV as it is the name of the flower, is there any other way to import this CSV file so that this issue isnt an issue?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use pandas:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv")
data.head() # to see first 5 rows
X = data.drop(["target"], axis = 1)
Y = data["target"]
```

or you can try (I would personally recommend to use pandas)

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Using your first solution, I get `KeyError: "['target'] not found in axis"` Have I miss understood? Do I need to replace the `"['target']"` with something?

Comment: so the target column would be your target values. Please change target as per your column name.

Comment: So, in my case, I want to get rid of the species names so I'd out that in the `x = data.drop(["species"]), axis =1 `, what would I put in the `y = data["target"]`

Comment: your Y should be "species". y = data["species"]